# Powershell FileSystemWatcher misses a change

Tags: powershell, event-handling, filesystemwatcher

I am trying to use the $FileSystemWatcher in powershell and it appears to miss some changes when generated by a program.

One of the application of the machine generates an xml file that contains parameters to produce a part. When I make a modification through the software that comes with the machine, I see that the last modified date is changed. However, I have no event getting registered.

If I take the xml file, open it, modify it and close it, then the event is registered.

Below is the code I used.

Any idea on the cause and solution for this?

```
    $PathToMonitor = "C:\Test"
$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.Filter= "product.xml"
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true

$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$previoustimestamp = $null
$previousfullpath = $null


# define the code that should execute when a file change is detected
$Action = {
    $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
    $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
    $FullPath = $details.FullPath


    if (($previoustimestamp -ne $Timestamp) -and ($previousfullpath -ne $FullPath)){
    $previoustimestamp= $Timestamp
    $previousfullpath = $FullPath


    $Name = $details.Name
    $FullPath = $details.FullPath
    $OldFullPath = $details.OldFullPath
    $OldName = $details.OldName
    $ChangeType = $details.ChangeType
    

    # you can also execute code based on change type here
    switch ($ChangeType)
    {
        'Changed' { "CHANGED" 
  
            $OriginalPath=$FullPath.split("\")
            $OriginalPath=$OriginalPath[0]+"\"+$OriginalPath[1]+"\"+$OriginalPath[2]+"\"+$OriginalPath[3]+"\"+  $OriginalPath[4]+"\"  
            
            $RecipeFolder=$OriginalPath.split("\")
            $RecipeFolder=$RecipeFolder[4]
            Write-Host $RecipeFolder[4]
            $OriginalRecipeFolder=$RecipeFolder
            $RecipeFolder+="_"+$timeStamp
            $NewRecipeFolder=$RecipeFolder.Replace("/","_").Replace(" ","_").Replace(":","_")
            $BackupPath=$OriginalPath.Replace("Products","Backup").Replace($OriginalRecipeFolder,$NewRecipeFolder)

        Copy-Item -Path $OriginalPath -Destination $BackupPath -Recurse

        Write-Host "Backup done of recipe $OriginalRecipeFolder from $OriginalPath to $BackupPath at $timeStamp because $changetype" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        
    }   
 }   
 }

}

# add event handlers
$handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Changed -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FsChange 
    #FSCreate FSDelete FSRename
}

Write-Host "Watching for changes to $PathToMonitor"

try
{
   do

    enter code here
    {
        Wait-Event -Timeout 1
       Write-Host "." -NoNewline
        
    } while ($true)
}
finally
{
    # this gets executed when user presses CTRL+C
    # remove the event handlers
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSChange
    # remove background jobs
    $handlers | Remove-Job
    # remove filesystemwatcher
    $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
    "Event Handler disabled."
}
```

Comment: If this behavior is consistent, I would suggest using something like [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see and compare the exact file system events affected when using the application software vs. editing the file directly.

Comment: Thanks. I used the tool and found out that the file uses a temporary buffer. It is working now.